# Printing out all possible combination of printable ASCII 7-bit characters to stdout

Tags: c, pointers

This takes over 60 minutes to execute. The program is small in size, about 16kb. I am thinking that the repeated calls to `printf` slows it down significantly, rather than the nested `for` loops.

I used:

> gcc -Wall -o charsprint charsprint.c ./charsprint

Without removing the `printf` call: How could this source code be smaller and/or faster? Can the nested for loops be condensed using pointers?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*
* print out all combinations of chars between 1 and 5 chars
* 88 keys
* char combinations:
* basic a-f[26+] 0-9[10+] SPACE TAB CAPSLK ,./;'[]\-=`[14+]
* SHIFT A-F[26+] <>?:"{}|~!@#$%^&*()_+[21+]
* 52+35 = 87 chars available
* 87^5 = 4 984 209 207 possible combinations
*/

char ascii[] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,
        0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f,
        0x10,0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,
        0x18,0x19,0x1a,0x1b,0x1c,0x1d,0x1e,0x1f,
        0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24,0x25,0x26,0x27,
        0x28,0x29,0x2a,0x2b,0x2c,0x2d,0x2e,0x2f,
        0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,
        0x38,0x39,0x3a,0x3b,0x3c,0x3d,0x3e,0x3f,
        0x40,0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44,0x45,0x46,0x47,
        0x48,0x49,0x4a,0x4b,0x4c,0x4d,0x4e,0x4f,
        0x50,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,
        0x58,0x59,0x5a,0x5b,0x5c,0x5d,0x5e,0x5f,
        0x60,0x61,0x62,0x63,0x64,0x65,0x66,0x67,
        0x68,0x69,0x6a,0x6b,0x6c,0x6d,0x6e,0x6f,
        0x70,0x71,0x72,0x73,0x74,0x75,0x76,0x77,
        0x78,0x79,0x7a,0x7b,0x7c,0x7d,0x7e,0x7f
        };

int main(void){
    int i,j,x,y,z;
    i = j = x = y = z = 0x00;
    char result[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    for (i=0x20; i<0x7e; i++){
        result[0] = ascii[i];
        for (j=0x20; j<0x7e; j++){
            result[1] = ascii[j];
            for (x=0x20; x<0x7e; x++){
                result[2] = ascii[x];
                for (y=0x20; y<0x7e; y++){
                    result[3] = ascii[y];
                    for (z=0x20; z<0x7e; z++){
                        result[4] = ascii[z];
                        printf("%s\n", result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nDone...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will probably be a lot quicker if you use `gcc -Wall -O3 ...`

Comment: It is almost certainly pointless to talk about optimizing this code while ignoring the `printf`. It is most likely responsible for the vast majority of your execution time, so optimizing the rest cannot help significantly (see: Amdahl's Law). You can verify this by profiling your code.

Comment: Or if you don't want to profile it, run a simple experiment: get rid of all the permutation code and simply print a static string 4984209207 times. That will put a lower bound on your run-time.

Answer (score 4):

It can be smaller if you remove the pointless `ascii` array, like this:

```
int main(void){
    int i,j,x,y,z;
    i = j = x = y = z = 0x00;
    char result[] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    for (i=0x20; i<0x7e; i++){
        result[0] = i;
        for (j=0x20; j<0x7e; j++){
            result[1] = j;
            for (x=0x20; x<0x7e; x++){
                result[2] = x;
                for (y=0x20; y<0x7e; y++){
                    result[3] = y;
                    for (z=0x20; z<0x7e; z++){
                        result[4] = z;
                        printf("%s\n", result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nDone...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And, it would seem logical that `puts(result)` should be faster than `printf("%s\n", result)`, though the compiler might optimize both to the same thing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Doing IO certainly slows a process down but have you looked at the numbers?

You want to print about 5 billion lines presumably to the console. You state it takes (over) 60 minutes at your place. This means you are printing (at most) 23k lines per second to produce a total of 30GB of data (6 Byte per line).

I used janos' code to test this on my machine with `-O3` and got 123k lines per second. Then I redirected the output to `/dev/null` and got 27M lines per second which finished your program in 3 minutes.

So the reason your program is slow is twofold: The program

1. creates an awful lot of data
2. is (presumably) outputting to a slow sink (the terminal)

The solutions are rather obvious:

1. Create less data, which might not be possible
2. Use a faster write target; options are:

   - memory
   - files

The terminal is so slow because it must display the data you are outputting, thus doing all kinds of additional work that slows down the process.

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered [this very similar question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/brute-force-algorithm-in-c), which basically asked the same question except they limited it to `a-z A-Z 0-9` (62 characters) instead of this question which uses 96 characters (that I counted).  So I took my program from that question and just added the extra characters.  When I ran it, I was able to output all 5 character combinations to `/dev/null` in 3.6 seconds.  Of course, outputting to an actual file takes a lot longer, but it really only measures the speed of your hard drive.

By the way, I also tested using `printf` and `puts` instead of `write`.  Using either `printf` or `puts` caused the program to take 13.1 seconds instead of 3.6 seconds using `write`.

See [my original answer to the other question here, where I explained my algorithm.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/brute-force-algorithm-in-c/74379#74379)  The modified program is as follows:

```
// Print all combinations of the given alphabet up to length n.
//
// The best way to test this program is to output to /dev/null, otherwise
// the file I/O will dominate the test time.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                       " \t,./;'[]\\-=`<>?:\"{}|~!@#$%^&*()_+"
                       "0123456789";

static void generate(int maxlen);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s Length\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    generate(atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Generates all patterns of the alphabet up to maxlen in length.  This
 * function uses a buffer that holds alphaLen * alphaLen patterns at a time.
 * One pattern of length 5 would be "aaaaa\n".  The reason that alphaLen^2
 * patterns are used is because we prepopulate the buffer with the last 2
 * letters already set to all possible combinations.  So for example,
 * the buffer initially looks like "aaaaa\naaaab\naaaac\n ... aaa99\n".  Then
 * on every iteration, we write() the buffer out, and then increment the
 * third to last letter.  So on the first iteration, the buffer is modified
 * to look like "aabaa\naabab\naabac\n ... aab99\n".  This continues until
 * all combinations of letters are exhausted.
 */
static void generate(int maxlen)
{
    int   alphaLen = strlen(alphabet);
    int   len      = 0;
    char *buffer   = malloc((maxlen + 1) * alphaLen * alphaLen);
    int  *letters  = malloc(maxlen * sizeof(int));

    if (buffer == NULL || letters == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // This for loop generates all 1 letter patterns, then 2 letters, etc,
    // up to the given maxlen.
    for (len=1;len<=maxlen;len++) {
        // The stride is one larger than len because each line has a '\n'.
        int i;
        int stride = len+1;
        int bufLen = stride * alphaLen * alphaLen;

        if (len == 1) {
            // Special case.  The main algorithm hardcodes the last two
            // letters, so this case needs to be handled separately.
            int j = 0;
            bufLen = (len + 1) * alphaLen;
            for (i=0;i<alphaLen;i++) {
                buffer[j++] = alphabet[i];
                buffer[j++] = '\n';
            }
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);
            continue;
        }

        // Initialize buffer to contain all first letters.
        memset(buffer, alphabet[0], bufLen);

        // Now write all the last 2 letters and newlines, which
        // will after this not change during the main algorithm.
        {
            // Let0 is the 2nd to last letter.  Let1 is the last letter.
            int let0 = 0;
            int let1 = 0;
            for (i=len-2;i<bufLen;i+=stride) {
                buffer[i]   = alphabet[let0];
                buffer[i+1] = alphabet[let1++];
                buffer[i+2] = '\n';
                if (let1 == alphaLen) {
                    let1 = 0;
                    let0++;
                    if (let0 == alphaLen)
                        let0 = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Write the first sequence out.
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);

        // Special case for length 2, we're already done.
        if (len == 2)
            continue;

        // Set all the letters to 0.
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
            letters[i] = 0;

        // Now on each iteration, increment the the third to last letter.
        i = len-3;
        do {
            char c;
            int  j;

            // Increment this letter.
            letters[i]++;

            // Handle wraparound.
            if (letters[i] >= alphaLen)
                letters[i] = 0;

            // Set this letter in the proper places in the buffer.
            c = alphabet[letters[i]];
            for (j=i;j<bufLen;j+=stride)
                buffer[j] = c;

            if (letters[i] != 0) {
                // No wraparound, so we finally finished incrementing.
                // Write out this set.  Reset i back to third to last letter.
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);
                i = len - 3;
                continue;
            }

            // The letter wrapped around ("carried").  Set up to increment
            // the next letter on the left.
            i--;
            // If we carried past last letter, we're done with this
            // whole length.
            if (i < 0)
                break;
        } while(1);
    }

    // Clean up.
    free(letters);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `puts(result);` certainly must be faster (or a fast) than `printf("%s\n", result);`.

A *very* good compiler would optimize that.