# C permutation generator

Tags: c, combinatorics

I am making a permutation generator in c. Any ideas how I can make it faster?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int n = 8, c[n], i, l = strlen(s);
    char w[n];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        c[i] = 0;
        w[i] = '\0';
    }
    w[n] = '\0';
    while(c[0] < l){
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            w[i] = *(s + c[i]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", w);
        c[n - 1] += 1;
        for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(c[i] > l - 1 && i != 0){
                c[i] = 0;
                c[i - 1] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially after JS1's suggestion, you're print bound. I time at least 90% of the runtime being in printing *after* my suggestion. I've no doubt buffering can improve that, but it seems like a waste to try. "how I can make it faster?" probably isn't a useful question.

Comment: If I undestand the problem correctly, you're trying to print all 8-char strings built with 26-letter alphabet without repetitions? If so, you're going to print about 2.5 times 10^15 strings...

Answer (score 2):

#### Buffer overrun

Your array `w` should be one larger than it currently is to hold a null terminating character.  Otherwise when you write to `w[n]` you are writing past the end of the array.

#### Excess copying

Currently, every time you generate a new permutation, you rewrite all of the `w` array.  You actually only have to rewrite the parts that changed since the last permutation.  To do this, you should write to `w[i]` only when `c[i]` changes.  So for example:

```
while(c[0] < l){
    c[n - 1] += 1;
    w[n - 1] = s[c[n - 1]];
    for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(c[i] > l - 1 && i != 0){
            c[i] = 0;
            w[i] = s[0];
            c[i - 1] += 1;
            w[i - 1] = s[c[i - 1]];
        }
    }
}
```

#### Alternate implementation

If you are looking to find a faster way to generate permutations, I suggest you look at [this codereview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/brute-force-algorithm-in-c) and in particular my answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix the buffer overrun, a quick improvement is to write

```
w[n] = '\n';
```

and then print with

```
fwrite(w, sizeof(char), n + 1, stdout);
```

Also, remember to `#include <string.h>`.